# mod_rewrite rules

Tags: php, html, apache, mod-rewrite, webserver

Hello, I am trying to set up my URL settings, and I have some requirements that I've already asked for, but my last problem was the following:

If a user, for example, tries to access `site.com/foo.php`, they should be redirected to `site.com/foo`; and conversely, if a user enters `site.com/foo` they shouldn't be redirected but the requested page should be `site.com/foo.php`.

Here is my .htacces:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(.*)\.html$
RewriteRule ^.*\.html$ %1.php [L]  

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ $1.php

AddType application/x-httpd-php .htm .html

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

Redirect /anmeldung http://www.site.com/register
Redirect /anmeldung.htm http://www.site.com/register
Redirect /anmeldung.html http://www.site.com/register
Redirect /anmeldung.php http://www.site.com/register

Redirect /registierung http://www.site.com/register
Redirect /registierung.htm http://www.site.com/register
Redirect /registierung.html http://www.site.com/register
Redirect /registierung.php http://www.site.com/register

Redirect /register.htm http://www.site.com/register
Redirect /register.html http://www.site.com/register
```

If there is someone who could help me out, I'd really appreciate it. 
Thanks a lot.

**UPDATE:**

The full htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

EewriteRule ^(.*)\.(php|html)$ /$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1.php [L]

Redirect /anmeldung http://www.site.com/register
Redirect /anmeldung.htm http://www.site.com/register
Redirect /anmeldung.html http://www.site.com/register
Redirect /anmeldung.php http://www.site.com/register
Redirect /registierung http://www.site.com/register
Redirect /registierung.htm http://www.site.com/register
Redirect /registierung.html http://www.site.com/register
Redirect /registierung.php http://www.site.com/register
```

Comment: I assume that what you are trying to say is that you if the user comes to *.php you want to rewrite the URL in the browser to be just *, but if the user comes to *  there will be no rewrite, but rather the script to process the file would be *.php?

Comment: ON your updated htaccess.  Is that just a typo of EewriteRule on the first line? It should obviously be RewriteRule.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on my assumption comment above you should try

```
# This rewrites all incoming request to *.php or *.html to remove the extension. NOte the R=301 which give header indicating to the browser/spider that the resource has been relocated. The L indicates this is the last rule to be processed before sending headers to browser (which will start the process all over again) This rule MUST be first
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.(php|html)$ /$1 [R=301,L]

#This set of conditions is only applicable if the request is not a directory, is not itself a file, and has a similarly name file with .php extension.  Here we do not perform a URL rewrite (i.e. [R]), but just pass this to the .php file as the last htaccess rule executed.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1.php [L]
```

Comment: Sorry had a few typos which should now be fixed.

Comment: thank you so far. i just wanted to test it. there is a problem with the root directory. entering site.com/foo.php leads to site.com/html/foo so it adds html before the *

Comment: There is not any rewrite here to add 'html/' to the URI.  Are there some other rules either in the Apache host config file or in the .htaccess file the were not shown in your original post?

Comment: just the redirects that i just added to my post above.

Comment: Hmm... odd.  can you post your apache host config?

Comment: seems that i have no access to that config directory on my webserver. my hoster denies this.

Comment: Oh you are in shared hosting environment?  Did they automatically direct everything to html directory before you started doing any rewrites?

Comment: yepp, thats exactly what it is.

Comment: Well regardless. The rewrite rules shown above should still work. As they are not specific to any directory.

Comment: i contacted my webhoster. still waiting for an answer.

Comment: For what it's worth. In this day and age of easily available super-cheap cloud-based dedicated servers, it is IMO crazy to be developing on shared servers where you have minimal control over the environment or security. But I know this is sometimes out of your control.

Comment: i have already resigned this contract. the support is still horrable... i`m so unsatisfied at all. do you have some alternatives which you can recommend?

Comment: okay, i have an answer from the support... its saying that  /html should not appear because the domain already shows on that. this entry i should remove from rewrites ??? sorry, i never had worked with that before. do you know where the mistake will be?

Comment: I pretty much use Amazon Web Services for most of what I am doing, so I am not up to speed on what the best options might be. I used to really like Slicehost, but haven;t used them in a while (at least since they were acquired by Rackspace) so I don't know how their service is.  They pretty much had push button server provisioning.

Comment: There is nothing in the htaccess that would do that redirect.  Does you hosting company allow you to view/modify the apache config file?

Comment: they say that this is not possible. whatever... okay, i thank you for helping me. i will leave at this point. regards from berlin, germany.